# How can I add custom attributes to opentelemetry hostmetricsreceiver

Tags: go, process, open-telemetry

I am using Opentelemetry Collector Contrib's hostmetricsreceiver
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/hostmetricsreceiver

I am specifically interested in the process scraper, so my otel-config looks like this :

```
receivers:
  hostmetrics:
    collection_interval: 1m
    scrapers:
      process:

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [ hostmetrics ]
      exporters: [ logging ]
```

Now, current configuration gives me following Resource level attributes for each process :

```
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "process.pid",
            "value": {
              "intValue": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "process.executable.name",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "api-server"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "process.executable.path",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "/bin/bash"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "process.command",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "/bin/bash"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "process.command_line",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "/bin/bash /usr/bin/api-server start"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "process.owner",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "root"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Now, let us say, **I want to add process start time as a new attribute here. How can I do that ?**

I read about https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/attributesprocessor and
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/hostmetricsreceiver

But, I guess these processors can only help me for adding attributes having `fixed` or `static` values.

Can I use these processors for my usecase ?
How do I approach adding such attributes in existing receivers ?